# Second tab disabling

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to detect my web application is getting loaded in second tab and stop it from loading from second tab?
I have a requirement that web application should run only on one tab, it should not get loaded on second tab.
 I used this code and it works perfectly as it gives alert on my first tab that second tab got loaded but I want that alert to come on second tab as sorry already one tab is open.

```
function register_tab_GUID() {
            // detect local storage available
            if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {


                // get (set if not) tab GUID and store in tab session
                if (sessionStorage["tabGUID"] == null) sessionStorage["tabGUID"] = tab_GUID();
                var guid = sessionStorage["tabGUID"];

                // add eventlistener to local storage
                window.addEventListener("storage", storage_Handler, false);

                // set tab GUID in local storage
                localStorage["tabGUID"] = guid;
            }
        }

        function storage_Handler(e) {
           // if tabGUID does not match then more than one tab and GUID
            if (e.key == 'tabGUID') {
                if (e.oldValue != e.newValue) tab_Warning();
            }
        }

        function tab_GUID() {
            function s4() {
                return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                  .toString(16)
                  .substring(1);
            }
            return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
              s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
        }

        function tab_Warning() {
            //alert("Another tab is open!");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`if (!window.sessionStorage['tabGUID']) window.sessionStorage['tabGUID'] = tabGUID();`

or

`if (window.sessionStorage['tabGUID'] !== undefined) window.sessionStorage['tabGUID'] = tabGUID();`

Testing against null will always return false unless you first set that value (`sessionStorage['tabGUID']`) to null. because by default JS returns undefined when a key does not exist in an object.

Answer (score 0):

-The only way to get an alert back to the current tab is to send a reqest to check if that session exist. A simple api request can be used and if you get a response, we can conclude that there is a current tab open.

- Each tab is fenced for security reasons so there is no way of accessing a session from another tab. If the user does not explicitly log off. Theres no way of knowing that there is a tab or not open.